# How to include a combination of term and terms filters inside a single bool filter in elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch, filter

I am using logstash to store logs in elasticsearch database. I want to get logs having a particular severitylabel and are between certain time stamps and matches to some specific message. The curl query I wrote is :

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/logstash-2015.06.19/_search/?pretty' -d '{
"query": {
    "filtered": {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {
                        "match": {
                            "@message": "session"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "filter": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {
                        "range": {
                            "@timestamp": {
                                "gte": "2015-06-19T10:11:44.000Z",
                                "lte": "2015-06-19T11:11:44.000Z"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "@app": "sparta"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "terms": {
                            "@severityLabel": [
                                "INFO",
                                "WARN",
                                "ERROR",
                                "FATAL",
                                "OFF"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
} } '
```

It always shows zero documents, matched. I am using term filter as a sibling of terms filter, is that a problem?

Comment: Looks good to me. Are you sure that fields "@message", "@app" and "@severityLabel" exist? If i remember correctly, logstash appends the "@: char to several fields (like timestamp), but not all of them....

Comment: Try to reduce your query and see where it fails. Note that you don't need a bool filter in the "query" part, but it don't hurt if it stays there.

Comment: @Roman I think it is "@severityLabel" only, the mapping shows "@severityLabel label". Link to my mapping :  http://pastebin.com/0yJy233L  , Also I am kind of new to elasticsearch. I know what's the difference between a query and filter. I wrote the query equivalent of this, which gives me hits. But I want to do it with filter and not with query. No score requirements. Link to the query equivalent of filter. http://pastebin.com/sxzpNX3e. Please help me with this, I am stuck like hell.

Comment: @rvheddeg What do you mean? Is this wrong, will it not do the required task of matching "@message" to the given string ( in this case "session" )? Or is the bool filter just redundant and there is some shorter way to write the  same query?

Comment: @NataniMayank What I mean is that the 2 bool queries are not linked. When you use a filtered query, the query and filter part are implicitely connected by a MUST filter. ElasticSearch will first evaluate the filter and then evaluate the query on the reduced dataset. So the first bool query can be eliminated in this example.